# Twinkling in sunlight reflections

Tags: optics

A question that covers optics and possibly biology/physiology: looking out my window, I see the Sun reflecting off car windshields in a distant parking lot. The very bright reflections are distinctly twinkling.

Is this twinkling false, and it's actually irritation to my eyes from the brightness (as well as tiny eye movements [saccades])? Or is it really twinkling, and if so, why? Other objects at that distance seem pretty steady. If the atmosphere is churning enough to cause the solar reflection to twinkle (either before or after the reflection), I would think everything else would twinkle too. Could the Sun heat up the cars enough to cause extra turbulence close to them, causing twinkling just in the line of sight to the reflection? If I had a pair of binoculars, I could consider checking out whether the rest of the car is twinkling (but would have to be careful about eye injury from the Sun's reflection!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost certainly due to atmospheric aberrations between you and the object. The aberrations between the Sun and the object are unimportant because that's not an imaged path. "Twinkling," whether from the reflective car or from stars at night, represent sudden changes in the phase front of light (due to atmospheric effects) which are then converted to amplitude changes via the usual Fourier Transform effect of the focussing lens -- or the lens in your eye.

But I really posted an answer just so I could quote:
" It all began with the tea---"
"Of course 'twinkling' begins with a 'T' !"

Answer (score 0):

Putting this in simpler language, winkling occurs because the turbulence the Earth's atmosphere produces inhomogeneity in the air refractive index that differs for hot and cold air. That is, hot and cold air refract the light a bit differently, acting like a large prism. That's why you see the light twinkling.

The same effect people call ``[shimmering](http://www.thenakedscientists.com/forum/index.php?topic=14849.0)'' - when in a hot summer day you look on a road and it appears twinkling.